# Only showing events outside a set time frame

Tags: google-calendar

Me and my wife are sharing google calendars to more easily manage our family schedule. I was also sharing my work calendar with her, so she would know when I had late meetings or events during the weekend.

But my work calendar is pretty busy, and she didn't like that her calendar was filled up with stuff that she had no interest in.

So is there any way to only share events that happen after, say, 6pm and during weekends? If there isn't, is there any way to hide the shared events in her calendar that happen between say 7am and 6pm?